# Stop Opera from autocomplete domains

Tags: opera, autocomplete

I want to make Opera behave like Firefox, i.e. search in local history / bookmarks, but not search online, sending addresses i type to the internets.

Answer (score 3):

The are different types of "suggestions/autocompletions":

- **Server Name Completion**

  If enabled, Opera tries to complete the typed in domain name (after pressing enter) by a prefix (per default `www.`) and a TLD (e.g. `.com`, `.net` etc.). So if you type into the address bar `asdfg/` (the slash is important) you probably will be directed to `www.asdfg.com` -- or if there's no DNS entry, Opera will try `www.asdfg.net`.

  Configuration via `Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Server Name Completion` or via various `opera:config` entried (search for `HostName`)
- **Addressbar Inline Completion**

  "Automatic completion of previously typed addresses in the address field" (Opera Help)

  Controlled by `opera:config#UserPrefs|AddressbarInlineAutoCompletion`
- **Addressbar Search Suggestions**

  While you are typing, Opera sends the query to a search engine (per default that's G**gle) to make suggestions what you possibly are looking for.

  Controlled by `opera:config#UserPrefs|ShowSearchSuggestionsInAddressfieldDropdown`

---

For those who never came across it, you can simply copy & paste these `opera:config...` URL's into the address bar and you'll end up at the correct position in the configuration list. Don't forget to press save after changing some options!

Comment: I actually meant proposals for address while typing, not authomatically adding something after enter is pressed.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Sorry, you need to be more precise. If you don't want addresses to be completed, disable `opera:config#UserPrefs|AddressbarInlineAutoCompletion`. But also with that enabled nothing is "sent to the internet" either. I guess that you don't want "search suggestion" -- that topic I addressed in the first part of my answer.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: I'll edit my answer to be more precise myself `;)`...

Comment: >@SmitJohnth: Sorry, you need to be more precise.< -> >behave like Firefox, i.e. search in local history / bookmarks, but not search online, sending addresses i type to the internets.< Leaking addresses I type is what I want to prevent.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Then disabling "Addressbar Search Suggestions" will comfort you, I suppose.

Comment: Turning off "Server Name Completion" does not work with Opera (12.16 on Debian Wheezy).  I turned it off and restarted, but Opera seems to ignore the settings and still keeps trying www.*