# how to stop autocomplete or web search from search and address bar in Opera v25

Tags: opera

I want to stop opera from completing url's as I type or from searching the web from the combined search/completion address bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop Opera from autocomplete domains](http://superuser.com/questions/561890/stop-opera-from-autocomplete-domains)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Opera Presto (up to 12.x), see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/561891/109305) as @Dave mentioned.

For the newer Opera Blink (version 15+), go to `Settings` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) > `Privacy & Security`, and uncheck this option:

`Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar`.