# Preventing all autocomplete suggestions in Opera's address bar

Tags: autocomplete, opera

I would like the address/search bar of my Opera browser to **not** make **any** suggestions to me as I write in urls or search queries. I find them highly distracting.

I tried solutions in an (much) older [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/561890/stop-opera-from-autocomplete-domains#) and some others I found through general web search but none have worked so far.

I'm using Opera version `42.0.2393.94` on a `Windows 10 64-bit` system.

Answer (score -1):

Try commenting out the "Suggest URL" line in your search.ini file:

```
;Suggest URL=http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?q={SearchTerm}&client=opera&hl=en
```

Comment: can´t find any file with that name (`search.ini`)

Comment: I can tell (from the fact that this shows a specific url) that this won't help with the problem in the question.

Comment: This is not surprising, as I have no knowledge of how to do this. Perhaps I left myself logged into someone else's computer, or perhaps I was just playing Drunk IT that night.